# How can I connect phpmyadmin that is installed on a host server to a maria db inside a running docker container?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I want to be able to control persisting data with Phpmyadmin from the host (outside) the running docker container which contains mariadb. I don't want to have phpmyadmin inside the container where my app is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the required database connection configuration to your phpmyadmin `/config.inc.php` file and connect to the Mariadb container.

Sample configuration would be as below

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = "127.0.0.1";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = "root";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = "password";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = "3306";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = "config";
```

Make sure your container port exposed to the host.